# How to deal with background modes in apple review

Tags: ios, gps, location, itunes, review

I have upload my app to itunes yesterday and i receive a mail from the apple that is:

From Apple
2. 5 Performance: Software Requirements
Guideline 2.5.4 - Performance - Software Requirements

We noticed that your app declares support for location in the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist file but does not have any features that require persistent location. Specifically, your app uses location background mode for the sole purpose of tracking employees, which is not appropriate on the App Store.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please revise your app to include additional features for your users that require the persistent use of real-time location updates while the app is in the background.

If tracking your employees' locations is your only intended use of background location, it would be more appropriate to distribute and sell your app as a custom B2B app through the Volume Purchase Program. Additional information about the Volume Purchase Program and the Custom B2B Store is also available in iTunes Connect Developer Help.

Request a phone call from App Review

At your request, we can arrange for an Apple Representative to call you within the next three business days to discuss your App Review issue.

To request a call and ensure we have accurate contact information, reply directly to this message with a contact name and direct phone number to reach you.

But fetching location in background is compulsory in my app.now what should i do whether reply them in notes or anything else??

Comment: why you require fetching location in background ? as apple says you are not using location in your app then why are you fetching ?

Comment: am using location in both foreground and background i think apple needs deep explanation that why am fetching location

Comment: let us know why you fetching location ? and how you are using that location ?

Comment: this app is for cleaner..so the company would track where the cleaner works

Comment: and how much time they worked..they also carrying our company vehicles..at that it will also needs for payroll and for their safety measurements

Comment: so you are fetching location in background but not showing anywhere in application on map or else and you just update that location to server right ?

Comment: updating to server also user user can view in mapview..

Comment: then you can mention that to apple that application also uses this to show on map and you should explain flow or purpose of the app that how you need location!

Comment: if explaining all things will help me

Comment: may be! you should try! or you can ask them suggestions also that if i want this functionality then how i should design my app!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple is very much strict with its background mode usage policies. If your app happened to use any of the background modes available, you better be sure that app adds the value to the user by opting the background mode.

**1. App using Location Changes to do some background stuff (adding no direct value to user)**

If your app uses user location changes just to do some background task (like uploading data to server or trying to keep ur app in sync with the server stuff like that), you must ensure you opt for `SignificantLocationChanges` only.

Make sure your location manager is observing significant location changes by using

```
[locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

rather than using `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];`

Using startUpdatingLocation will cause your app continuously monitor user location changes and will result in battery drain out. Which anyway is not appreciated by apple as your app is not using the location data directly.

**2.App using Location changes and adding value to user (Like map app)**

If your app on the other hand needs to monitor user location constantly and your app uses user location to actually add value to user like tracking user and showing it in map or something like that, you can use `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];`

But because startUpdatingLocation makes your app monitor location changes constantly, make sure you set `distanceFilter` and `desiredAccuracy` properly and does not exploit the location background mode unnecessarily.

**Finally:**

1. Make sure you add `Privacy - Location Always Usage Description` key to your info.plist and provide a detailed text explaining user why is your app uses his location info.
2. Go back to itunesConnect account, write a detailed explanation as to why is your app using location background mode and how it adds value to user and provide the steps to see how it reflects in app.

Hope it helps.

Comment: now i have reply them with appropriate reasons for why am fetching location in background and also with contact number also includes continued use gps in background can dramatically decrease your battery life in app description..will this support me

Comment: am fetching location for every 5 minutes by using timer only so i think there would be no problem with [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

Comment: @user3549189 : Just writing to apple will not help if you are using location unfairly. Make sure you use proper location manager API based on your need and also make sure u explain it to them when you resubmit it to review why u use it n how u think its important

Comment: i have not explained them deeply that why am fetching location now i have include in review notes and description

Comment: they itself asked a contact information..may i know how they need it??

Comment: Fetching location every 5 minutes using startUpdatingLocation not a great idea. startUpdatingLocation monitors location changes completely. So if use keeps walking for the 5 minutes it will keep monitoring user location whole 5 minutes. which will not be appreciated by apple if u don't use location fairly. Rather use significant location changes and remove the logic of 5 minutes. If location delegates din trigger that means user haven't moved in last 5 minutes. Thats all.

Comment: If your explanation doesn't satisfy them they might give u a call or preferably will write a mail :D

Comment: @user3549189 : Please consider accepting the answer if it helped