# App rejected while updating location in background modes

Tags: ios, background, location, app-store, mkmapview

From Apple
2. 5 Performance: Software Requirements
Guideline 2.5.4 - Performance - Software Requirements

We noticed that your app declares support for location in the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist file but does not have any features that require persistent location. Specifically, your app uses location background mode for the sole purpose of tracking employees, which is not appropriate on the App Store.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please revise your app to include additional features for your users that require the persistent use of real-time location updates while the app is in the background.

If tracking your employees' locations is your only intended use of background location, it would be more appropriate to distribute and sell your app as a custom B2B app, directly to CBS Clean, through the Volume Purchase Program. Additional information about the Volume Purchase Program and the Custom B2B Store is also available in iTunes Connect Developer Help.

Request a phone call from App Review

At your request, we can arrange for an Apple Representative to call you within the next three business days to discuss your App Review issue.

To request a call and ensure we have accurate contact information, reply directly to this message with a contact name and direct phone number to reach you.

i have developed a app for cleaners..cleaners location should be fetch in background for their payroll calculations and safety measurements..and also cleaners can view their worked places in mapview...but my app gets rejected..now what should i do..how to deal with this issue

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44299255/how-to-deal-with-background-modes-in-apple-review/44299745#44299745 I have explained in detail.

Comment: It sounds like the issue is that this app is not of general use; it is for the use of employees of a specific organisation. This combined with a fairly aggressive privacy-related issue; continual tracking of employees *without specific benefit to the user from this tracking*  has lead to your app's rejection. You could either use an enterprise distribution path as suggested or perhaps provide a way for the user to easily turn tracking on/off (such as begin/end shift buttons), but in general AppStore approval questions are off-topic for SO as this is something you need to resolve with Apple.

Comment: yes i made this app for use of cleaners for specific organisation.

Comment: now what should i do

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37948301/apple-app-store-rejection-5-1-5).

You can include the functionality and methods for the location services if your app needs Location services or remove the Location Updates from the `UIBackgroundMode` key in info.plist, So that your app will be approved by **App Store**.

I think you are using

> locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

use this `locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` instead.

Comment: Im fetching location in background so am using locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()..and also turned on location updates in background modes'

Comment: ok, so you have to explain to them that why you are using the background location fetch. Have a look at the link i provided in the answer!

Comment: i will look and reply

Comment: i have explained them cleanly why am fetching the location in background..but still am getting this as issue

Comment: Are you done with the description in the plist file?

Comment: You mean  displaying description that why customer need to allow the location services when alert appears.am right??

Comment: yes i have included description that why am fetching location